# How to identify the meaning of the mYear element in this structure？

Tags: c++, c, windows, time, struct

I had some question on Windows SYSTEMTIME struct description and explanation

The Windwos SYSTEMTIME struct is like this

```
typedef struct _SYSTEMTIME {
  WORD wYear;
  WORD wMonth;
  WORD wDayOfWeek;
  WORD wDay;
  WORD wHour;
  WORD wMinute;
  WORD wSecond;
  WORD wMilliseconds;
} SYSTEMTIME, *PSYSTEMTIME;
```

and the MSDN's explanation about the wYear is like this

```
The year. The valid values for this member are 1601 through 30827.
```

Now I got a SYSTEMTIME structure and the `wYear=834h`

How do I know how much the corresponding year is?

---

#### NOTE:

Q: *How did you get this SYSTEMTIME?*

A: *I am doing a reverse analysis of the virus with `IDA pro`, this structure is derived from the assembly code of the virus*

---

Q: *There is no magic offset, it starts at 0. You've got garbage data*

A: *I am sure about this is NOT garbage data, because this value is artificially given, the source assembly code is shown like this `mov [esp+40Ch+SystemTime.wYear], 834h`*

Comment: How did you get this `SYSTEMTIME`? I would assume that the content is garbage.

Comment: In regard to @VTT's comment: are the other members making sense? If not the "garbage" idea becomes even more probable.

Comment: There is no magic offset, it starts at 0.  You've got garbage data.  Stack buffer overflow, maybe.

Comment: I am doing a reverse analysis of the virus, and I see the virus use this strutuce to SetWaitableTimer~

Comment: What makes you think a virus wouldn't generate "_garbage data_"? I've no idea whether it _can_ be used to exploit something, but deliberately using illegal values is the sort of thing you can almost expect a virus to do. But in any case, `834h` is `2100` (decimal) so the value is valid anyway.

Comment: Ok, maybe I just found the answer right now~THX guys

Answer (score 0):

> wYear=2001 represents the time in 2001
>
> wYear=1989 represents the time in 1989

This is answer, I made a math error in calculating the hexadecimal to decimal, sorry guys~

Happy autumn~